# How to show another HTML file's contents on the same page when a link is clicked?

Tags: javascript, html, anchor, href

When I have a couple of links on the left side of my page, how do I show another HTML file's contents on the same page when a link is clicked?

Comment: Examples?  What is `another html`?  The better the question the better the answer will be.  Try to be as detailed as possible.  Also mention WHAT YOU HAVE TRIED so we may better see where you are going with this.

Comment: what im trying is next...I have links on my left side...i need to show text from this link  in the same page where the links are....

Comment: Do you want to load another page, or actually print out the html code on screen?

Answer (score 2):

Simple solution: `iframe`s, nicer but slightly harder solution: `AJAX`.

- iFrame
  To create an iframe put this in your source code: `<iframe src="the/URL/of/a/page.html"></iframe>`. That would display the file at `the/URL/of/a/page.html` in the iframe. An iframe can be styled with CSS (just FYI). Then give all your `<a>`s a class, I took `link` for my example JavaScript, and the iframe an ID (I took `iframe`). (There is no way to do it without JS AFAIK, or you would have to use a `<frameset>`, which is deprecated.) The example JS:

  ```
  var links = document.getElementsByClassName("link"); // Get all the elements with the class link

  for (var i; i < links.length; i++) { // Loop over all the links
      links[i].onclick = function(e) { // Tell them what to do when they're clicked
          e.preventDefault(); // Prevent the browser from navigating to the address of the links href
          document.getElementById("iframe").src = links[i].href; // Set the iframe's src to the href of the a.
      }
  }
  ```
- AJAX
  That's a little bit harder, and using a library like [jQuery](http://jquery.com) simplifies this task enormously. In my example I use jQuery, otherwise it would have taken much more lines of code.
  You need a `div` to display the loaded page, put one on your page and give it an ID (I used `resultbox` in my example). Note that AJAX normally only works with files from the same domain, contrary to the `iframe` solution (although I believe I saw some workarounds/hacks on SO). The example:

  ```
  $(".link").click(function(e) { // If an element with the class 'link' get's clicked...
      e.preventDefault();
      $("#resultbox").load("the/URL/of/a/page.html"); // ... load the contents of the file at the/URL/of/a/page.html into the element with the ID 'resultbox'
  });
  ```

Note: I didn't test any of this.

Comment: The OP didn't mention the 'other HTML' would be from another domain, so I automatically assumed it would be just a navigation bar. Thank you for pointing this out, I will include it in my answer @cIph3r

Comment: Better, however with hacks on SO, you probably refer to JSONP, proxy files or cross domain policy files

Comment: I didn't think the OP was up to this yet, so I didn't extend on it, but: yes, you're right. @cIph3r